# AlamofireObjectMapper Cannot invoke 'responseObject' with an argument list of type '((User?, NSError?) -> _)'

Tags: swift, alamofire

I use the AlamofireObjectMapper framework in swift and as said in https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper i want use "responseObject" with a custom class but it doesn't work:

code:

```
let URL = "http://37.187.145.241:8080/MasterMarket/api/users-maxou/2"
        Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
            .responseObject { (response: User?, error: NSError?) in
                println(response?.company?.nameCompany)
                println(response?.lastNameUser)
        }
```

My custom class User :

```
class User : Mappable {

var idUser : Int?
var firstNameUser : String?
var lastNameUser : String?
var phoneNumberUser : String?
var parent : User?
var removeUser : Bool?
var managerRightsUser : Bool?

var company : Company?
var genderType : GenderType?
var userType : UserType?
var deposit : Deposit?

var createdUser : String?
var modifiedUser : String?

init() {}

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    mapping(map)
}

func mapping(decoder: Map) {
    idUser <- decoder["idUser"]
    firstNameUser <- decoder["firstNameUser"]
    lastNameUser <- decoder["lastNameUser"]
    phoneNumberUser <- decoder["phoneNumberUser"]
    removeUser <- decoder["removeUser"]
    managerRightsUser <- decoder["managerRightsUser"]

    parent <- decoder["parent"]
    company <- decoder["company"]

}
```

and the error :

```
Cannot invoke 'responseObject' with an argument list of type '((User?, NSError?) -> _)'
```

Comment: did you find the answer? if so please share

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, actually the error was not concerning the responseObject() method but the request() one.

The solution was to specify the type (String) of my parameters array for the request method. You don't have any parameters, maybe add :String for your url ?

Comment: Now it's works like this:
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
            .responseObject{(responseBody:User?,error: NSError?) in

Comment: Hi...I am having the same issue..can't quite understand what you have changed in the answer..can you please help

Comment: If you don't find the solution, look at the request() method and not the responseObject().

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the library to version 2.1.
Then you could use:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
        .responseObject({ (response: Response< User, NSError>) -> Void in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print(response.result.value)
            }
        })
```

Good luck!